# Foreign keys problems in SQL table while entering data with C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have created these tables in SQL Server:

**Subject**

- SubjectID (PK)
- SubjectName
- Mark

**Class**

- ClassNo (PK)
- HomeRoomTeacher (FK)
- StudentID (FK)

**Subject_Class**

- SubjectID (PK)
- ClassNo (PK)

**Teacher**

- TeacherID (PK)
- TeacherName
- ClassNo (only the HomeRoomTeacher has the assigned class)

**Student**

- StudentID (PK)
- StudentName
- ClassNo (FK)

I want to input the following data to the corresponding tables.

- Subjects: English, Maths, Physics, Chemistry, Geography, History & Science
- Class   : 5A,5B,5C,6A,6B,6C,7A,7B,7C,8A,8B,8C,....
- Student : John, Mary, Kaito,........
- Teacher : Mark, Jane, Rosy,......

Then I tried to input data using C# form. But the exception dialogbox says conflicts with the foreign key constraint. All the tables are linked each other.
How can I solve this problem?

Is there a table that I should input data first?

P.S: I am looking for some courses or information that I can learn how to build applications using C# with a SQL Server databases and what to do if there is any conflicts because of foreign keys and composite keys in SQL Server while inserting information using C# Windows Forms.

I am doing my first project after learning a few basic of C# and SQL Server and I found some problems that I cannot find the solutions. Because all courses that I have learnt so far has taught about how to manipulate data and how important relationship between tables and using foreign keys and composite keys. But none of them has shown me how to apply them in the real projects and real applications.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't insert data into a table that has a foreign key until the related table's (the one with the primary key) data is inserted. Also, I question why your `Class` table has `StudentID`. Is it 1 student to 1 class?

Comment: When you have a primary key one row of the table can have the same key.  Foreign must have a Primary key with same column name in another table.   HomeRoomTeacher should be changed to TeacherID.  Also make sure you do not have any nulls in a column with a primary key.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Based on the above comments you should be fixing the code of inserting data. If you still having issues, you need to share the code. Without seeing the code we can't say what mistake you are doing in the code and can not suggest any solution.